# Find specific word and list all file names in PHP

Tags: php

I am yet to work on a very large project which has too many files. I am trying to find out few vaiables where it is present and list all the file names which contains the specific word or variable or string.

What I have tried so far!

```
$path = realpath(__DIR__); // Path to your textfiles 
$fileList = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($fileList as $item) {
    if ($item->isFile() && stripos($item->getPathName(), 'php') !== false) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($item->getPathName());
    $file_contents = strpos($file_contents,"wordtofind");
    echo $file_contents;
    }
}
```

I use the same code for replacing text which I found it on stackoverflow. But I need to find out few strings before replacing specific words in specific files. Hence this has become most important task to me.

How can I further code and get the file names?

Edit:
I want to search for a specific word, for example: `word_to_find`
And there are more than 200 files in a folder called abc.
When I run that code, searching for the word, then it should search in all 200 files and list all the file names which contains `word_to_find` word.

Then I would know, in which all files, the specific word exists and then I can work on.

Output would be:

```
123.php
111.php
199.php
```

Comment: I recommend you read this guide [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), on how to ask good questions. I need more to work with here. As it sits it's a bit confusing to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Give us an example, of the directory structure, and some files, and what you're attempting to get from those files, from this function.

Comment: Skip php use grep fro the command line

Comment: To clarify what Dagon said, what are your plans for this code? Is this something for the end user, or (by the looks of it) is it for your purposes to find code within files? If you're on a *nix machine, grep can be used from the command line fairly easy to locate files. I am working on your PHP solution tho (PHP Playground disables file functions, so I had to download WAMP).

Comment: No, its for development use and not for end users. I am preferring in PHP rather than GREP from command line. There is also a reason, am unable to find few functions which was developed by my ex-developers and am unable to locate in on my local machine.

Comment: Are you working onto a linux server? Need the code to be in PHP?

Comment: Yes, for linux and require in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created you a nice function. This will return filenames (Not any paths, yield `$item->getPathName()` instead if you want the path, or probably better yet, just yield `$item`, which will return the [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) class which you can then use any of the helper functions to get info about that file.):

```
function findStringInPath($needle, $path = __DIR__) {
    //$path = realpath(__DIR__); // Path to your textfiles 
    $fileList = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($fileList as $item) {
        if ($item->isFile() && strtolower($item->getExtension()) === 'php') {
            $file_contents = file_get_contents($item->getPathName());
            if ( strpos($file_contents, $needle) !== false )
                yield $item->getFileName();
        }
    }
}

foreach ( findStringInPath('stringtofind') as $file ) {
    echo $file . '<br />';
}

?>
```

For older PHP versions:

```
<?php

function findStringInPath($needle, $path = __DIR__) {
    //$path = realpath(__DIR__); // Path to your textfiles 
    $fileList = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($fileList as $item) {
        if ($item->isFile() && strtolower($item->getExtension()) === 'php') {
            $file_contents = file_get_contents($item->getPathName());
            if ( strpos($file_contents, $needle) !== false )
                $ret[] = $item->getFileName();
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

foreach ( findStringInPath('stringtofind') as $file ) {
    echo $file . '<br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the function, am getting error as `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$item' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/.......`

Comment: What php version are you running? Try the second code block, if the first isn't working. `Yield` is a relatively new keyword introduced in version 5.5

Comment: PHP version 5.4.28, I think `yield` requires > 5.5

Comment: Perfectly working. Am just being greedy here for realpath of the file. Any example using `SplFileInfo` within your function.

Comment: Just do `$ret[] = $item` in the function. Down below, you can use things like `$file->getPath()` or `$file->getSize()` to get the size of the file. Returning the `$item` object (An instance of `SplFileInfo`) gives you more flexibility to get the things you want outside of the function.

Comment: Yes, great, worked as required. Thank you so much and really appreciate your help and efforts. Upvoted and accepted.